# fgetc reads wrong characters from file

Tags: c

I use fgetc to read characters from a file and it reads something strange.

I have this in the txt file:
[image]

But when i look at the file info it shows this:

[image]

and fgetc actually reads the { as first character of the file instead of S.

I tried to change the file extension to rtf,txt, no extension but same result.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What program are you using to create this file. It seems to be RTF, not a simple ASCII format file. The issue is not your C program.

Comment: Created it with another editor. its working great now

Comment: Please mark the question as answered...

Comment: I did already...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you wrote the file in some sort of editor that stores its metadata at the beginning of the file.  Try recreating the file with a more basic editor that does just text editing.  Or from the command line echo "my file contents" > myfilename.txt.

Comment: I'm not an apple user but I believe a program called "notes" is suitable for basic text editing.  Otherwise any code editor should do the job (like Visual Studio Code or Notepad++).